# Matlab to openCV code conversion

Tags: matlab, opencv

I am trying to convert a code in MatLab to OpenCV but I am stuck about the following lines as I don't know much programming

**MatLab code:**

```
[indx_row, indx_col] = find(mask ==1);
Indx_Row = indx_row;
Indx_Col = indx_col;

for ib = 1:nB;
    istart = (ib-1)*n + 1;
    iend   = min(ib*n, N);
    indx_row = Indx_Row(istart:iend);
    indx_col = Indx_Col(istart:iend);
```

**openCV code:**

```
vector <Point> index_rowCol;
for(int i=0; i<mask.rows; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<mask.cols; j++)
    {
        if( mask.at<float>(i,j) == 1 )
        {
            Point pixel;
            pixel.x = j;
            pixel.y = i;

            index_rowCol.push_back(pixel);
        }
    }
}


//Code about the "for loop" in MatLab code
for(int ib=0 ; ib<nB; ib++)
{
    int istart = (ib-1)*n; 
    int iend = std::min( ib*n, N );

    index_rowCol.clear();// Clearing the "index_rowCol" so that we can fill it again from "istart" to "iend"4
    for(int j = istart; j<iend; j++)
    {
        index_rowCol.push_back( Index_RowCol[j] );
    }
}
```

I am unable to understand if it is ok or not?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do using this Matlab code ? There may be an easier way to achieve this using OpenCV.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is mistake in usage of [min](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) function.
Here

```
for ib = 1:nB;
    istart = (ib-1)*n + 1;
    iend   = min(ib*n, N);
```

ib - is array [1,2,3..nB] and you compare each value with N. As the result you also get array.

So as result: 
ib - is array, istart - is array and iend also an array.

In C++ implementation

```
for(int ib=0 ; ib<nB; ib++)
{
    int istart = (ib-1)*n; 
    int iend = std::min( ib*n, N );
```

you work with scalars (here ib,istars and iend are scalars).

For better understand how the code above works use step-by-step debugging. (Set breakpoint and run the code then press (F10 key-for matlab) )